# SSL requests failing in production only

Tags: java, ssl, httpclient

I have a Java webapp deployed on a Tomcat 7 running with Java 7 (Oracle JVM).

All my Apache HTTPClient request to external HTTPS urls are failing (in production only) and I don't quite know why. I have checked the cacerts truststore that comes installed with the JVM and all the certificates are valid.

I have downloaded the JVM and Tomcat directories to my development machine and have run the webapp (with the same paths, same parameters, etc.) and it works.

Executing a standalone JAR that makes an HTTPS request in production works as well.

At this point, I'm out of ideas frankly.

This is the example code that fails:

```
  InputStream is=null;

  HttpParams httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();
  HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParams, 2000);
  HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParams, 2000);

  DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParams);
  try {
      httpclient.getParams().setParameter("http.useragent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1)");
      HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();

      HttpHead httphead = new HttpHead(url); 
      HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httphead, localContext);

      HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url); 
      response = httpclient.execute(httpget, localContext);

      HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
      is= new ByteArrayInputStream(EntityUtils.toByteArray(entity));

  } catch (IOException ie) {
      throw new IOException("IO exception",ie);
  } finally {
      httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
  }
  return is;
```

Example of stacktrace:

```
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSessionImpl.getPeerCertificates(SSLSessionImpl.java:421)
        at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AbstractVerifier.verify(AbstractVerifier.java:128)
        at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:390)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:148)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:149)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:121)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:561)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:415)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:820)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:754)
```

Tomcat JAVA_OPTS:

```
JAVA_OPTS="-server -Xms4g -Xmx4g -XX:PermSize=512m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/lib/security/cacerts -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=changeit"
```

Comment: You should check the SSL certificates for any of your accessed urls using some CLI tool from the actual production server and check if this certificate matches the one that you get locally, for example by using your browser. See [this question](http://serverfault.com/questions/661978/displaying-a-remote-ssl-certificate-details-using-cli-tools) for some of your options. Maybe there is some proxy in place that terminates remote SSL?!

Comment: @dpr Thanks, sadly they match. I'm connecting to well known services such as imgur or mailgun.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the certs in the cacerts file bundled with Oracle Java didn't contain the root certs of the websites to which I was sending the requests. I replaced that file with the cacerts file from the OpenJDK package and everything is working again.

Answer (score 3):

Hard to tell without access to your environments. First things I'd check:

- make sure that you are really using the JVM and trust store you think you are using
- check the .ssh directory in your user home directory.
- do you have any ssl tools running locally, like plink?
- do you have any environment variables set up, pertaining to SSL?
- What are the firewall settings on the production server?

Comment: 1. I did check if I was running the correct JVM by running ps aux | grep java. 2. Why should I check the .ssh directory? 3. I'm not running any ssl tools. 4. Tomcat is running under www-data user and here are the environment variables: http://pastie.org/10983959 5. iptables: OUTPUT ACCEPT http://pastie.org/10983960

Comment: The only thing that did change is that I switched the site from HTTP to HTTPS, but I did that by configuring Cloudflare. My own nginx and tomcat run on HTTP.

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure the https with port 8443
please refer below link for more details
https://www.mkyong.com/tomcat/how-to-configure-tomcat-to-support-ssl-or-https/

Comment: Tomcat is running on HTTP. The SSL termination is done on Cloudflare.